# Spring Cloud Deployer Local is unable to spin up worker remote partitions when server.port property is set in master's application properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-task

I am trying to build a batch service in an existing application that has server.port=8080 property configured in application.properties file. When I run the batch process and Spring Batch trying to bring up  remote partitions(separate JVMs), spring cloud deployer local throws error saying
"\r\n\r\n***************************\r\nAPPLICATION FAILED TO START\r\n***************************\r\n\r\nDescription:\r\n\r\nThe Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.\r\n\r\nAction:\r\n\r\nVerify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

Is there a way to make the framework generate random ports for worker partitions being the server.port property that is already configured in the application.properties as is?

Thanks.

Comment: A Spring Batch remote partitioning setup requires a message broker for the communication between the manager and workers, but it does not requires any web capabilities. You seem to be deploying all your apps **locally** (manager and workers) as web applications, hence the port conflicts when multiple workers are deployed. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, yes you are correct. I am trying to deploy my complete application for workers as well. What would be the alternative for it? Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Spring Batch remote partitioning setup requires a message broker for the communication between the manager and workers, but it does not require any web capabilities. You seem to be deploying all your apps **locally** (manager and workers) as web applications, hence the port conflict when multiple workers are deployed.

You have at least two options:

- Either set a random server port for each app (See how Spring Boot allows you to do that [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-random-values))
- Or, if the number of workers is fixed, set ports to distinct values statically.